# MenuRef GetControl32BitValue always return 0

Tags: menu, macos-carbon

Hello i' need to use a pop-up menu, witch is created dynamically.

```
OSErr err = GetBevelButtonMenuHandle(m_pRecallAOptionalButton, &m_pRecallAMenuRef);

for (countitem)
{
 String szItem (List.GetAt(i));
 CFStringRef sz = ToCFStringRef(szItem);
 AppendMenuItemTextWithCFString(m_pRecallAMenuRef, sz, 0, 0, 0);
}

short  sCount = CountMenuItems(m_pRecallAMenuRef);
SetControl32BitMaximum(m_pRecallAOptionalButton, sCount);
```

This is ok, menu show the correct number of items. I set maximum value.

My problem occur when i want to get the selected item index.
For this, i use the kEventClassMenu event & kEventMenuClosed kind

```
case kEventClassMenu:
{
    MenuRef Menu;
    GetEventParameter( inEvent, kEventParamDirectObject, typeMenuRef, NULL, sizeof(Menu), NULL, &Menu );

    if (Menu && (Menu == pMainForm->m_pRecallAMenuRef))
    {
      SInt32 nIndex = GetControl32BitMaximum(m_pRecallAOptionalButton); // return the correct items count
      nIndex = GetControl32BitValue(m_pRecallAOptionalButton); // always return 0 !!!!!
    }
}
```

Did i missed something ? is it the right event to attach ?

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to handle kEventClassCommand/kEventProcessCommand, and use the command id from the menu item.

```
HICommand           command;

GetEventParameter( inEvent, kEventParamDirectObject, typeHICommand, NULL,
            sizeof( HICommand ), NULL, &command );

switch (command.commandID) {
    case 1:
      ... etc ...
```

Note that the commandID is one of the parameters to `AppendMenuItemTextWithCFString`; that's how you can give each item a unique commandID as you generate the menu. commandID's are conventionally 4-char codes (like 'open' or 'save'), but there's no reason you couldn't use simple ints for your dynamically-generated commands.

Comment: Thanks, but this what i'd like to avoid (generating a 4-char code), i really need an index.

Comment: You're missing the point: the commandID is simply a 32-bit int (UInt32). While it's conventional to use meaningful 4-char codes for menu items created using interface builder, there's no reason you can't use sequential integers if that's what works best for you.